# How can I pivot one column of unique IDs to show all matching secondary IDs in adjacent columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got one column with Primary ID numbers, and each of these Primary ID numbers can have up to 3 Secondary ID numbers associated with it.  I want to pivot the secondary IDs so they all appear in up to 3 columns to the right of just one instance of each Primary ID.

Currently it looks like this:

| Primary ID | Secondary ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 234234 |
| 1 | 435234 |
| 1 | 22233 |
| 2 | 334342 |
| 2 | 543236 |
| 2 | 134623 |
| 3 | 8475623 |
| 3 | 3928484 |
| 4 | 3723429 |
| 5 | 3945857 |
| 5 | 11112233 |
| 5 | 9878976 |

I want it to look like this:

| Primary ID | Secondary 1 | Secondary 2 | Secondary 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234234 | 435234 | 22233 |
| 2 | 334342 | 543236 | 134623 |
| 3 | 8475623 | 3928484 | - |
| 4 | 3723429 | - | - |
| 5 | 3945857 | 11112233 | 9878976 |

Not sure how to get the column headers there and probably where my issues are coming from when I try to use pivot or pivot table with pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index='Primary ID',
        columns=df.groupby('Primary ID').cumcount().add(1),
        values='Secondary ID'
    ).add_prefix('Secondary').reset_index()
)
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.assign(t=df.groupby('Primary ID').cumcount().add(
    1)).set_index(['Primary ID',  't']).unstack(-1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   Primary ID  Secondary1  Secondary2  Secondary3
0           1    234234.0    435234.0     22233.0
1           2    334342.0    543236.0    134623.0
2           3   8475623.0   3928484.0         NaN
3           4   3723429.0         NaN         NaN
4           5   3945857.0  11112233.0   9878976.0
```